# Button Panel.ZIndex is not working when Button Stack Panel is placed inside the ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have created a Stack panel with 10 buttons. Whenever i put the focus on the buttons it must be expanded and if i remove the focus it must come to the normal size.

I have done this by using rendering concept and Panel.ZIndex.

But if i keep the StackPanel into ScrollViewer then Button expansion is not visible, that is expanded button is going inside the ScrollViewer.

But the expanded button must be visible fully.

Please help me how to do this

I have attached my sample solution [here](http://cid-ab034720ad5419bf.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/ksvimal%20files/WpfApplication13.zip).

In the sample solution, First 2 rows button panels are placed inside the respective scrollviewer.

I want the first 2 row buttons shud work same as the last row buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Panel.ZIndex only determines the relative z-order of controls within the same container. Furthermore, what you're describing is not related to z-order but rather the clipping behavior of ScrollViewer. ScrollViewer clips its rendering to the bounds of the visible content area. Therefore anything inside of the ScrollViewer that tries to render outside of its bounds will be hidden. You can't simply turn off clipping or else the ScrollViewer will be useless.

What you may be able to do is use a Popup and position it manually over the button. It's not pretty but this is how context menus and tool tips work.

Comment: So, there is no way rendering the buttons outside the scrollviewer?

Comment: If there is a way other than using another rendering layer such as popup or adorner layer, I do not know of it.

Comment: popup is the only option.  even an adorner of items in the scrollviewer will get clipped

Comment: Hi, I came through the these links... They have solved similar problem by using the Canvas... But i could not understand it exactly.. Can you please explain the same??? whether i need to keep a canvas panel around each button???  http://www.netframeworkdev.com/windows-presentation-foundation-wpf/canvas-scrollviewer-resize-problems-95961.shtml      http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/19063e31-9b80-471a-9e9c-eb45d5b5f8d7/